# How to get only functions with ctags

Tags: parsing, ctags

How do you generate ctags only for functions and ignore typedefs and structs?
I've tried `ctags --declarations --output=tags program.c`, but I have to manually parse this functions. 
I've tried: `ctags -x --c-kinds=fp path_to_file. 2`, but I get the following error:

```
ctags: unrecognized option '--c-kinds=fp'
    Try `ctags --help' for a complete list of options.
```

Edit:
After I installed exuberant, the following does the trick to get only function headers:

```
ctags -x --c-types=f ./prog.c
```

For anyone who stumbles across this question, if you want the entire function (header and body), you'll need to write a script for that. But it's not too hard. I'm using the function headers as, essentially, indices. Just read and find where each function header is in the file to get a unique index - some function names are the same, so iterate over the code and use a while to only add and continue to look in the code for that function until it gets a different index from those in your list of indices. Save the function name and position in a list of tuples and then sort the list in ascending order. Then read the code extracting functions by starting from the top at the first function and reading to the next one in the list. You may have to do some variation of this depending on your situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are using [*Exuberant Ctags*](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/). On my system:

```
$ ctags --version
Exuberant Ctags 5.8, Copyright (C) 1996-2009 Darren Hiebert
  Compiled: Nov 11 2010, 03:54:52
  Addresses: <dhiebert@users.sourceforge.net>, http://ctags.sourceforge.net
  Optional compiled features: +wildcards, +regex
```

Your system must have symbolically linked `etags` to `ctags`. When I do so, I replicate your error message. However, the unknown option error using *Exuberant Ctags* shows as:

```
ctags: Unknown option: --foo
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need to generate function declarations from your source, you can easily do it with a little ctags and sed magic:

```
ctags -x --c-types=f source.c|cut -c51- |sed -e 's/$/;/g' > header.h
```

Comment: What if the definition spans more than one line?